# Need help refactoring my firebase function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase function that sends an email, updates a record on another collection and creates an account on another API service when a new user is created. The whole operation runs for 2 minutes but I think it can be optimized further. I'm also new to async await so I don't really know how to use it properly.

```
exports.onCreateUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const updateOtherCollectionRecord = async () => {
       
       const values...
       ...
       return admin
              .firestore()
              .collection('others')
              .doc('id')
              .update(values);
    }

    const sendEmail = async () => {
       const url...
       ...
       return await axios
                    .post(url,data,config);
    }

    const createAccount = async () => {
       const url...
       ...
       return await axios
                    .post(url, data, config);
    }

    updateOtherCollectionRecord();
    sendEmail();
    createZendeskAccount();
})
```

Right now, those functions runs synchronously. I was hoping to refactor using Promise.all but not sure how to use it. I tried it but it's not triggering the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your functions are declared `async`, you need to use the `await` keyword when calling them. And consequently you need to declare the Cloud Function itself as `async`.

So the following should do the trick:

```
exports.onCreateUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {  // <=== See async here

    const updateOtherCollectionRecord = async () => {
       
       const values...
       ...
       await admin      // <=== See await here
              .firestore()
              .collection('others')
              .doc('id')
              .update(values);
    }

    const sendEmail = async () => {
       const url...
       ...
       await axios
                    .post(url,data,config);
    }

    const createAccount = async () => {
       const url...
       ...
       await axios
                    .post(url, data, config);
    }

    await updateOtherCollectionRecord();
    await sendEmail();
    await createZendeskAccount();
    return null;
});
```

---

From what you explain in your question, there is no real need for using `Promise.all()`: there will always be three calls to asynchronous functions, you can very well do them sequentially.